# Angular 4: Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'

Tags: asp.net, node.js, angular

**Before you mark it as duplicate please read:**

Hi I'm learning Angular 4 with ASP.Net Core and came into this issue.
I've read probably all similar issues where the solution is to add `FormsModule`, this doesn't work with my issue. 
The strange thing is when I comment out the line with ngModel and run it, it works. When I uncomment and only save in VS2017 it automatically updates application and two way binding works until I refresh the page.

**app.module.client.ts:**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { sharedConfig } from './app.module.shared';


@NgModule({
bootstrap: sharedConfig.bootstrap,
declarations: sharedConfig.declarations,
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    ...sharedConfig.imports
],
providers: [
    { provide: 'ORIGIN_URL', useValue: location.origin }
]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

**app.component.html:**

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<div *ngIf="selectedhero">
    <h2>{{selectedhero.name}} details!</h2>
    <div><label>id: </label>{{selectedhero.heroNo}}</div>
    <div>
        <label>name: </label>
        <input [(ngModel)]="selectedhero.name" placeholder="name">
    </div>
</div>

<div class='container'>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>

<h2>heros</h2>
<ul class="heros">
    <li *ngFor="let hero of heros"
        [class.selected]="hero === selectedhero"
        (click)="onSelect(hero)">
        <span class="badge">{{hero.name}}</span> hero {{hero.heroNo}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

**app.component.ts:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

export class hero {
    lineId: number;
    heroNo: number;
    name: string;
    statusCode: number;
}

const HEROS: hero[] = [
    { lineId: 2, heroNo: 1, name: '1', statusCode: 5 },
    { lineId: 2, heroNo: 2, name: '2', statusCode: 5 },
    { lineId: 2, heroNo: 3, name: '3', statusCode: 5 },
    { lineId: 2, heroNo: 4, name: '4', statusCode: 5 },
    { lineId: 2, heroNo: 5, name: '5', statusCode: 5 },
    { lineId: 2, heroNo: 6, name: '6', statusCode: 5 },
    { lineId: 2, heroNo: 7, name: '7', statusCode: 5 },
    { lineId: 2, heroNo: 8, name: '8', statusCode: 5 },
    { lineId: 2, heroNo: 9, name: '9', statusCode: 5 },
    { lineId: 2, heroNo: 10, name: '10', statusCode: 5 },
    { lineId: 2, heroNo: 11, name: '11', statusCode: 5 },
    { lineId: 2, heroNo: 12, name: '12', statusCode: 5 }
];

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
    title = 'My Heroes';
    heros = HEROS;
    selectedhero : hero;
    onSelect(hero: hero): void {
        this.selectedhero = hero;
    };
}
```

Comment: Do the same things for server module. Import FormsModule

Comment: Which aspnet.core + angular template are you using?

Comment: wow, it works:) Thank you, but I'm sure I have tried this before Do you know why they split module into 3 separate ones?

Comment: @yurzui if you add it as answer I will mark it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should import `FormsModule` for server module as well.

According to https://github.com/MarkPieszak/aspnetcore-angular2-universal#client---everything-angular

> With Angular Universal, we need to split our applicatoin logic per
>   platform so if we look inside this folder, you'll see the 2 root
>   files, that branch the entire logic for browser & server respectively.
>
> - **Main.Browser.ts** - This file starts up the entire Angular application
>     for the Client/browser platform. Here we setup a few things, client
>     Angular bootstrapping.
>
> You'll barely need to touch this file, but something to note, this is
>   the file where you would import libraries that you only want being
>   used in the Browser. (Just know that you'd have to provide a mock
>   implementation for the Server when doing that).
>
> - **Main-Server.ts** - This file is where Angular platform-server serializes
>     the Angular application itself on the .NET server within a very quick
>     Node process, and renders it a string. This is what causes that
>     initial fast paint of the entire application to the Browser, and helps
>     us get all our SEO goodness